# Improper functioning of packages in R Studio

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I have installed the following packages in my R studio version 1.0.153.

```
library(bupaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(processmapR)
library(processmonitR)
library(xesreadR)
library(edeaR)
```

I have used these packages for over months now but suddenly when I execute any function from above library like:

```
sepsis %>%trace_explorer()
patients %>% process_map(), I get the following error:

Error in is_null(nms) : object 'rlang_is_null' not found
```

What is the issue, I am not able to understand, please help as it is not making any sense to me why some package would instantly stop functioning.

Comment: Could you share the versions as I am not able to get the error message and is working fine i.e. `xesreadR_0.2.1      processmonitR_0.1.0 processmapR_0.2.0   eventdataR_0.1.1    petrinetR_0.1.0     edeaR_0.7.1         bupaR_0.3.0 dplyr_0.7.4`

Comment: @akrun, same as yours, thanks for replying, I just don't get it, what happens to the tool at some times. I just can't figure what went wrong there

Comment: Also I see something damn weird, in the data pane on right, there is a variable I stored as "abcz" which has a data frame. But when i run the variable in command line, rather that displaying data, it gives the error "object 'rlang_is_null' not found:

Comment: Some packages contain same functions name (but different functionality), have you tried to use `packageName::functionName()` in your case? That might help. e.g. `dplyr::select()`